# Long running process on Azure SharePoint Virtual machine

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, virtual-machine, azure

I started a SharePoint Virtual machine, and I ran a process that might take 2-3 days to complete. However, once I close the remote connection, Windows closes the session, and it seams like everything is paused. Can I prevent this?